# Android : How to set MediaPlayer volume programmatically?

Tags: java, android, media-player

How to set the mediaplayer volume programmatically. I use it for alarm notification. Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using **AudioManager**, you can simply control the volume of media players.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

also from MediaPlayer (But I didn't try that)

```
setVolume(float leftVolume, float rightVolume)
```

> **Since: API Level 1**
>
> Sets the volume on this player. This API is recommended for balancing
>   the output of audio streams within an application. Unless you are
>   writing an application to control user settings, this API should be
>   used in preference to setStreamVolume(int, int, int) which sets the
>   volume of ALL streams of a particular type. Note that the passed
>   volume values are raw scalars. UI controls should be scaled
>   logarithmically.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> leftVolume     left volume scalar
>
> rightVolume    right volume scalar

Comment: what is the minimum volume to set with value?

Comment: if 0, it takes no volume. If 1, it is ringing with full volume on the device.

Comment: What is the 20 number? I thought you said volume was from 0 to 1?

Comment: 20 is the max volume number (0 is minimum). But I've found out this can be different per device. You can get the max volume number using audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType) and do some nice math if you'd like adjust it in a more controlled way ;-)

Comment: I personally prefer setVolume as it provides far more fine-grained control and is not dependent on the Output device (for example a bluetooth headset might have even less volume steps)

Comment: Note that setVolumes value range (0.0-1.0) is relative to the current media volume. So if the media volume is 0, then it won't matter what the value is, no sound is coming out :)

Answer (score 26):

Hope this help

```
    audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

For **Volume UP**

```
 audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

for **Volume Down**

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Comment: hi dwivedi ji, can we adjust notification sound through our device's volume button ?

Comment: Is there a way to raise the volume of the actual `MediaPlayer` file, not the phone volume? I am getting a `MediaPlayer` whose playback is very low, even if the phone volume is normal.

Answer (score 6):

You do have the `setVolume` method in the `MediaPlayer` class. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29)

Answer (score 4):

To Hide Volume Controll UI:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

For Volume UP

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
```

for Volume Down

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the below using `Kotlin`, this code will check if the media volume is more than 20% of the maximum volume of the device, and will reduce it to be 20% only.

```
    val audio = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

    val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    val percent = 0.2f
    val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

    if ( level > twintyVolume) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"audio level is $level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)
    }
```

Comment: twintyVolume is nice)

Answer (score 2):

Read this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html) right here. It explains very well.
Basically, unless your app is a replacement alarm clock, you need to make the following call in the "onCreate()" function:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

In this way you can create the volume of your app using the hardware buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set left and right speaker volumes.

```
if (System.nanoTime() == alarm){
    yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
protected static void setVolume(int volume) {
        currentVolume = volume;
        {
            if (volume == 1) {
                volume = 2;
            }
            try {
                float vol = ((float) volume / CONSTANT.SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(vol, vol);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code sets the volume to the maximum level (getStreamMaxVolume()).

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
try 
 {        
   float count = 100 * 0.2f;
   Log.d("--count_float", count + "");
   Log.d("--count_final", Math.round(count) + "");
   Log.d("--count_volume", new 
   PreferenceMotionSensor(mContext).getStreamVolume());
   mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Math.round(count), 0);
 } 
catch (Exception e) 
 {
  Log.d("--Error", e.getMessage());
 }
```

**Output**

```
D/--count_float: 20.0
D/--count_final: 20
D/--count_volume: 100
```